# How to use Session_End when website timesout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, timeout, session-variables

I know I have to add Session_End method to the global.asax file but I do not know what to put inside the method for it to end the current session when the website timesout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for expiration of the session you could set a time fot this. just place this code in your web config 1 = 1min,

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
        </system.web>
```

Comment: I dont necessarily want it to timeout before the website timesout.  I just want the session to end when website isnt live on the browser anymore

Comment: every time you use a session the time will just reset...

just place a code to use a session every time you have an activity in your page.

Comment: and if you close your browser for 1min it will expire because you dont have an activity in your page

Comment: OOOOO, i didnt know that. let me give it a try!

Comment: just read the cookies that you created or use it in an IF statement